# KIA Oprius / Amanti 2006 instrument cluster pinout, wiring diagram

Tags: electrical, wiring, kia, instrument-cluster, amanti

I am currently doing an instrument cluster swap, but I need the pinout or wiring schematics for it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Before you take either instrument cluster out, test each wire for the function it does - make notes of the main color and the race color and the position in the plug as they may not be in the same positions...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I already have written down what each pin does in my car but unfortunately I can't do the same on the donor car (The car in question KIA Opirus). I only have the instrument cluster itself. That's why I need the pinout.

Comment: I would get a battery or power supply, suitably fused, and provide each pin on the cluster with power and work out the functions like that, but that's just me...

Comment: Haha looks like we both think the same. I did like you said and sort of figured out what pin does what but I still have some unknown pins. Worst case scenario I can make it work with the information I have at the moment but I don't wan't to rush it.